# Change property from event handler

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I want a progressbar to be visible until a download is finished.

In order to do that, I bind the "Visibility" property with an attribute called "loadBarVisibility".

XAML Code :

```
<ProgressBar Visibility="{Binding loadBarVisibility}" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
```

ViewModel Code :

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public static Visibility loadBarVisibility { get; set; }
    private const String URL = "myurl";


    public MainViewModel()
    {

        loadFlux();


        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
            // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        }
        else
        {
            // Code runs "for real"
        }
    }


    public static void loadFlux()
    {
        loadBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(URL));
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(test_downloadFinished);



    }


    public static void test_downloadFinished(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {

            loadBarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        }

    }

}
```

But the code above doesn't work : the progressbar is still visible.

Otherwise, **when I put "loadBarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;" just after             "client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(test_downloadFinished);", it works.**

Is there a way to solve my problem ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ViewModel need to implement the interface INotifyPropertyChanged to notify you're view that the property visiblilty was changed (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Comment: I added :
    new public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

But i can't call NotifyPropertyChanged because "loadbarvisibility" is a static attribute (can't call from the setter)..

Comment: Methods and property in you viewmodel should not be static. For a good overview of the pattern MVVM please look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx